# what reference I need to add in C# to get LaunchPadApi?

Tags: c#

I try to connect to the API (Using C#) that client provided, but it is using LaunchPadApi() I am not sure what assembly I need to add to get this, these are 2 references that were added:

```
using IO.Swagger.Api;
using IO.Swagger.Client;
```

I was able to find using IO.Swagger.Client; but I am not able to find using IO.Swagger.Api;

This is a sample code I am not sure how I can get LaunchPadApi defined so "responsePost" method is not recognized as well,

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using IO.Swagger.Api;
using IO.Swagger.Client;
using IO.Swagger.Model;
public class responsePostExample
   {
       public void main()
        {
        var apiInstance = new LaunchPadApi();
          ....
         try
           {
              apiInstance.responsePost(body, xAPIKey);
           }           
          ....
```

Answer (score 1):

- Install Launchpad in your nuget package manager for the project
- Add `using Launchpad;` to the top of your file

Comment: still    LaunchPadApi apiInstance = new LaunchPadApi(); is not recognized.